# Applying a force in a list of wires using Verilog

Tags: verilog, testbench

I want to apply a force command in a list of wires in Verilog.

My netlist looks something like this:

```
module ADDER(data_a, data_b, data_r);
input [7:0] data_a, data_b;
output [7:0] data_r;
wire n_0, n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4, n_5, n_6, n_7;
```

I want to apply a force sequentially for all wires from n_0 to n_7.

```
(#DELAY)
force   TB_ADDER.UADDER0.n_0=1;
...
(#DELAY)
force   TB_ADDER.UADDER0.n_7=1;
```

How can I do it in an easier way using concatenation and `for` style statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verilog does not support using a variable for different hierarchical paths.  This means you can not use a `for` loop to index the different signal names `n_0` through `n_7`.  There is no way to use fewer statements to force the signals than to do what you are already doing:

```
(#DELAY) force TB_ADDER.UADDER0.n_0=1;
//...
(#DELAY) force TB_ADDER.UADDER0.n_7=1;
```

If you could change the `ADDER` design to use an 8-bit bus (`[7:0] n`) instead of 8 separate 1-bit signals, then it may be possible to use a variable.

Comment: What if the nets are a result from a synthesis? Can I do something like a string array with force?

Comment: @JorgeJohannySáenzNoval: I can not think of any way to force different hierarchical paths in a loop with syntax supported by the IEEE Std 1800 for Verilog.  Some simulators may have proprietary ways to do so, but they are not applicable to all simulators.